# Migration problem between different machines using TrouSerS TPM library

Tags: encryption, authentication, key-exchange, tpm

My question coincides with the question [posted by Maximiliano Ezequiel](https://sourceforge.net/p/trousers/mailman/message/31183287/). Below is a question.

> I could make migration process work in one single machine. I can:
>
> 1. Export SRK public key.
> 2. Authorize Ticket.
> 3. Create Blob.
> 4. Load blob and encrypt info.
> 5. Load blob and decrypt info.
>
> But, when I execute step 1 in machine ONE, move public key output file
>   to machine TWO, authorize and create blob on it, and move back blob to
>   machine ONE to load it and start encryption and decryption, I receive
>   this error message on method `Tspi_Context_LoadKeyByBlob`:
>
> *Decryption error*
>
> Same code works perfectly at each one of these machine, both of them
>   have same owner password and srk password.... I think problem is in
>   migration password, but Im not sure...
>
> Would you mind helping me, please ?

As I can see from the Internet pages, it is a common problem which doesn't  have any proper public answer.  I would be very grateful for the resolution of this issue!

Comment: Experiments show that the problem is in rewrap mechanism. Interesting, that the decryption of the migration blob is possible using the same TPM device, where migration blob was created. It means that migratable key was re-wrapped by the wrong public RSA.